# Pands:add many series generate by loop to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I generate the `ts` series(contain index and one column data), and then add  series to `df` dataframe one by one  in the loop. But the `df` is an empty dataframe, it looks like using `pd.concat` is wrong. How to initialize a `df` to match series frame when looping?

My purpose is adding all series to a dataframe. Please give me two methods: one reserved single index,the rest is column data, and the other one reserved each series contain index and one column data one by one.

```
sites = pd.read_excel(sitefile,index_col = 'site',header=0)

for file in os.listdir(root):
    ......

    df = pd.DataFrame()                   # how to establish a df used to add new series data
    for i in sites.index:
         loni,lati = sites.loc[i,['lon','lat']]
         dsloc = ds.sel(lon = loni,lat = lati,method = 'nearest')

         #follow code  main relate to this question
         ts = pd.Series(dsloc[vname],index=dsloc['time'],name = i) # i in loop is a list of names ,used to name the sereis.
         df = pd.concat([df,ts],axis=1,join_axes=[df.index])
    df.to_csv(csvfile) # the fist answer remind me that df.to_csv should jump out of the loop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick, simple way would be to just add a conditional so that your first loop (i = 0) creates the dataframe:

```
for file in os.listdir(root):
    for iter, i in enumerate(sites.index):
         loni,lati=sites.loc[i,['lon','lat']]
         dsloc = ds.sel(lon=loni,lat=lati,method='nearest')

         ts=pd.Series(dsloc[vname],index=dsloc['time'],name=i)
         if iter==0:
            # First iteration, create the DataFrame
            df=pd.DataFrame(ts)
         if iter>0:
            # All other iterations, add to the DataFrame
            df=pd.concat([df,ts],axis=1,join_axes=[df.index])
         df.to_csv(csvfile)
```

I don't have a sample of your data so I'm not sure that code will run.

Also, your code as written produces a .csv file during every loop. I'm not sure if that was your intent, but to just produce one final csv of everything you should move the last line outside the for loop.

Comment: Actrully, the `i` in loop is used to name the series. The `site.index` is a list of names. I think it  could not use `if i==0` to generate a `df`

Comment: @Cobin Ah, my apologies. I have edited my answer to use enumerate() to keep track of the iteration using the counter "iter" while preserving i as the site name.

Comment: Thx very much! I'll try it. This solution is useful in my data operation.